# How to get Complex relation in a Laravel using eloquent

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

I have below tables

Users

```
id
name
```

Companies

```
id
user_id
name
```

Product Categories

```
id
company_id
name
```

Products

```
id
product_category_id
name
```

Sales

```
id
product_id
price
quantity
total
```

Now i want to get all sales for specified user's products. I have tried with below query. But i cannot use where for this. It is not apply this filter. Also i want to filter it by few other fields like users.user_name, products.product_name ... etc

```
$sales = Sale::with(['product'=>function($q) use ($user_id) {
        $q->with(['product_category' => function($q) use ($user_id) {
            $q->with(['company'=> function($q) use ($user_id) {
                $sUserName = Input::get('sUserName');
                $q->with(['user'=> function($q) use ($sUserName,$user_id) {
                    $q->where('id', $user_id);
                }]);
            }]);
        }]);
    }]);
```

Is it possible to use Eloquent for these situations ? Or should i use join queries ? Please advice me. thanks

Comment: i suggest you add a user id to the sales table

Comment: you don't have concrete fundamental, robust data modeling then how do you expect to have desired result using tool?

Comment: Thanks for the advise. Now i want to have another field for the ordered_user_id in the sales table. So then can i search it by givin user's name ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use laravel eloqunt like this.

$Sales = DB::table('Sales')
        ->join('Products', 'Sales.product_id', '=', 'Products.id')
        ->join('ProductCategories', 'ProductCategories.id', '=', 'Products.product_category_id')
        ->join('companies', 'ProductCategories.company_id', '=', 'companies.id')
        ->join('Users', 'companies.user_id', '=', 'Users.id')
        ->select('Sales.*')
        ->get();

Answer (score 0):

After [madalinivascu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1906356/madalinivascu) advise i could be able to resolve my problem as below. Now i can filter it by Ordered User, Product name & dates.

```
$sUserName = Input::get('sUserName');
    $sProductName = Input::get('sProductName');
    $sFrom = Input::get('sFrom');
    $sTo = Input::get('sTo');

    $user_id = \Auth::User()->id;


    // Show sales only for his products
    $sales = Sale::with('sold_to_user')
        ->whereHas('sold_to_user', function($q) use ($sUserName) {
            if(!empty($sUserName)) $q->where('name','LIKE', "$sUserName%");
        })->with('product')
        ->whereHas('product', function($q) use ($sProductName) {
            if(!empty($sProductName)) $q->where('name','LIKE', "$sProductName%");
            });

    if(\Auth::User()->privilege!='administrator') $sales = $sales->where('user_id','=',$user_id);


    $sales = $sales->orderBy('updated_at','desc')->paginate(100);
```